# Rendering a view after multiple asynchronous ajax calls with Backbone

Tags: jquery, ajax, backbone.js

I have a backbone view and I want to render html AFTER 2 asynchronous calls have been:

```
initialize: function (model, options) {        
    team.fetch({
                success: function (collection) { 
                  //do some things            
           });

    goal.fetch({
                success: function (collection) { 
                  //do some things          
           });

    this.render();
}

    render: function () {
        this.$el.html(template());
        return this;
    }
```

Obviously, with the code above, the html template will be returned before/during the ajax calls. Normally, when just one ajax call, I do:

```
initialize: function (model, options) {      
    var that = this;
    team.fetch({
                success: function (collection) { 
                  //do some things     
                          that.render();
           });


}

    render: function () {
        this.$el.html(template());
        return this;
    }
```

What's the most elegant way for doing this with multiple ajax calls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use the [JQuery Deferred](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Deferred/) implementation, specifically [`$.when`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/).  This lets you take an action only when multiple async operations have completed.  Use it like this:

```
var ajax1 = team.fetch({ ... });
var ajax2 = goal.fetch({ ... });

$.when( ajax1, ajax2 ).done( this.render );
```

**Edit**

As @muistooshort points out, you also have to bind `render`, so that it gets called with the correct context (otherwise `this` inside `render` would refer to the ajax object instead of the view object):

```
_.bind(this.render, this);
```

Comment: Will `render` be called in the correct context? I think the pending edit is trying to sort that out.

Comment: Just curious, would render have the context of the last ajax call to finish without the this/self context stashing?

Comment: @CoryDanielson oh, good catch ... the self/this stashing is not necessary there.

Comment: thanks, its working. Note that .done must take an anonymous function, otherwise it evaluates straight away and render is called before ajax calls have finished. I've added an edit which is pending

Comment: @user1716672 does it work if you use `.done(this.render)`, without the parentheses?  I thought that would be correct.

Answer (score 1):

Just so you can appreciate what jQuery Deferred is saving you from, this is an example of how you'd solve this very common problem without it. (Imagine writing this same code for 4 collections/models, not just 2.)

```
initialize: function(model, options) {
    team.fetch();
    goal.fetch();

    this.listenTo(team, 'sync', this.teamFetched);
    this.listenTo(goal, 'sync', this.goalFetched);
},

teamFetched: function() {
    this._teamFetched = true;
    // if goal also fetched, call & return this.render()
    return (( this._goalFetched ) ? this.render() : this);
},

goalFetched: function() {
    this._goalFetched = true;
    // if team also fetched, call & return this.render()
    return (( this._teamFetched ) ? this.render() : this);
}

render: function() {
    this._goalFetched = this._teamFetched = false;

    this.$el.html(template());
    return this;
}
```