# Render View with Multiple ajax Calls -

Tags: jquery, ajax, backbone.js

I have already seen the similar question in SO
[Rendering a view after multiple asynchronous ajax calls with Backbone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18925792/rendering-a-view-after-multiple-asynchronous-ajax-calls-with-backbone)

And unfortunately , the solution is behaving weird for me
I can see the render is getting called before the ajax completes

This my Code

```
var LoginView = Backbone.View.extend({

  initialize : function(){
        var _this = thisl
        var templateLoading  = $.get('template.html', function(template){
                  this.template = template;
        });

     $.when(templateLoading).done(function(){ _this.render()});
  },

render : function(){
    console.log('Rendering');
    $.tmpl(this.template).appendTo(this.el);
}

});
```

AppRouter:

```
//Route
var view = new LoginView;
console.log('View in APP Router');
console.log(view.$el.html());
```

When i run this, it prints in this order

```
View in App Router
empty string
Rendering
```

what am I missing ?

Comment: i think scope issue on var templateLoading  = $.get('template.html', function(template){ this.template = template; }); + you typo var _this = thisl instead var _this = this;

Comment: Leave the typo. Scope?? What do you mean.?? cant get you

Comment: try $.get('template.html', function(template){ console.log(this) }); and you will see what 'this' on this callback, then try try $.get('template.html', function(template){ console.log(_this) }); and check the diff

Comment: Edited my Question: Made it a bit clear
"this" is never a problem. i can see the render is getting called which by definition says, the "this" is not the callback instance but the Views. My question , why the order is different.

Comment: whats wrong with order? its correct.. you init view, it cals async $.when, then first  console.log - 'View in App Router', correct, then you log html , as render calls after async $when - its empty string, when $when completed calls .render - you get Rendering in console.

Comment: Ok to put it another way.. When I call view.$el. I want the view to be rendered doing all the ajax calls. How can I achieve it. I asked the render to wait , but its not waiting

Comment: view.$el - its just a property, you cant catch the moment you read it. wrap you have to start digging http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Deferred/ or use requirejs for module loading

Comment: Require js???? Am already using it.. And does it come here.. and am using when and done. Already deffered